# Check whether an event exists using graph api of facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to check whether an event exists on Facebook with an Event ID using Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this query `$facebook->api('/Event ID')` returns an error then the event doesn't exist for sure. If it returns data, you may want to check whether it really is an event - it might be a page or a person (any object in the Open Graph).

Answer (score 0):

Querying `/{event-id}` edge returns the event information if it exists.

If the edge returns an exception, that means either the event doesn't exist or the event is private and the person that the passed access token belongs doesn't have the permission to query the event.

To verify if it is an event, we can check if the response JSON has `start_time` key.